# Pre test to automate the access token in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I tried to automate my postman test. In first test I should get access token to execute the API call.
So I write pre test below. But I am getting 'There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:Error: No data, empty input at 1:1 ^'. I tried commenting last section but it's not worked.

How should I automate this ?

```
const tokenUrl = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/token';

const clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

const getTokenRequest = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: tokenUrl,
  body: {
      mode: 'formdata',
      formdata: [
          { key: 'grant_type', value: 'Client Credentials' },
          { key: 'client_id', value: clientId },
          { key: 'client_secret', value: clientSecret }
      ]
  }
};

pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
const jsonResponse = response.json();
const newAccessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;

  pm.variables.set('access_token', newAccessToken);

  });
```

Comment: do you mean pre-request script in postman?

Comment: also you are not setting headers with content type, also try either response.text() or  pm.variables.set('access_token', newAccessToken.access_token). or check in console what is newAccessToken and what is response

Comment: Yes Pre request  script

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: I tried above, but no success.

Comment: Error is : There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:Error: No data, empty input at 1:1 ^

Comment: Can you show the Postman Console output for this request or any images of the app? Does this request actually successfully complete as a stand alone request?

Comment: I am not getting any console output.